# phoenix table select join return Failed after attempts=11

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

## I get an error when I execute the following statement:

```
SELECT r.*, 
       l.productid, 
       l.prodname, 
       l.projnum, 
       l.projname, 
       l.capitalnumb, 
       l.fundname, 
       l.channelno, 
       l.channelname, 
       l.merchantno, 
       l.merchantname, 
       l.staff_name, 
       l.busipers 
FROM   lake.lake_retu_record r 
       LEFT JOIN lake.lake_loan l 
              ON r.loanacno = l.loanacno 
WHERE  r.acdate = '20200912000000' 
LIMIT  1000
```

### table information:

`lake.lake_retu_record  size:40MB  data：44000 pieces of data`
`lake.lake_loan         size:1.5GB data: 1700000 pieces of data`

### version:

`HBase-Version : 2.1.0`
`Phoenix-core: 5.0.0-cdh-6.2.0`

I am searching for a long time on net. But it doesn't solve the problem. Please help or try to give some ideas how to solve this.
I tried to modify these parameters `phoenix.query.queueSize phoenix.query.threadPoolSize phoenix.query.targetConcurrency phoenix.query.maxConcurrency`

### Exception:

```
    20/10/18 10:35:50 WARN client.SyncCoprocessorRpcChannel: Call failed on IOException
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=11, exceptions:
    Sun Oct 18 10:35:08 CST 2020, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1602988506012, pause=100, maxAttempts=11}, java.io.IOException: Call to CQ-HM-ALIFC-test/10.10.10.10:16020 failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    Sun Oct 18 10:35:08 CST 2020, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1602988506012, pause=100, maxAttempts=11}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Call to CQ-HM-ALIFC-test/10.10.10.10:16020 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
    Sun Oct 18 10:35:09 CST 2020, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1602988506012, pause=100, maxAttempts=11}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Call to CQ-HM-ALIFC-test/10.10.10.10:16020 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
    Sun Oct 18 10:35:10 CST 2020, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1602988506012, pause=100, maxAttempts=11}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Call to CQ-HM-ALIFC-test/10.10.10.10:16020 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
    Sun Oct 18 10:35:11 CST 2020, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1602988506012, pause=100, maxAttempts=11}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Call to CQ-HM-ALIFC-test/10.10.10.10:16020 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
    Sun Oct 18 10:35:12 CST 2020, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1602988506012, pause=100, maxAttempts=11}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Call to CQ-HM-ALIFC-test/10.10.10.10:16020 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
    Sun Oct 18 10:35:15 CST 2020, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1602988506012, pause=100, maxAttempts=11}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Call to CQ-HM-ALIFC-test/10.10.10.10:16020 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
    Sun Oct 18 10:35:19 CST 2020, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1602988506012, pause=100, maxAttempts=11}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Call to CQ-HM-ALIFC-test/10.10.10.10:16020 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
    Sun Oct 18 10:35:29 CST 2020, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1602988506012, pause=100, maxAttempts=11}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Call to CQ-HM-ALIFC-test/10.10.10.10:16020 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
    Sun Oct 18 10:35:40 CST 2020, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1602988506012, pause=100, maxAttempts=11}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Call to CQ-HM-ALIFC-test/10.10.10.10:16020 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
    Sun Oct 18 10:35:50 CST 2020, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1602988506012, pause=100, maxAttempts=11}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Call to CQ-HM-ALIFC-test/10.10.10.10:16020 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
    
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCallerImpl.java:145)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.callExecService(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:91)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.SyncCoprocessorRpcChannel.callMethod(SyncCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:52)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.ServerCachingProtos$ServerCachingService$Stub.addServerCache(ServerCachingProtos.java:8484)
        at org.apache.phoenix.cache.ServerCacheClient$3.call(ServerCacheClient.java:494)
        at org.apache.phoenix.cache.ServerCacheClient$3.call(ServerCacheClient.java:462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$12.call(HTable.java:997)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Call to CQ-HM-ALIFC-test/10.10.10.10:16020 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.IPCUtil.wrapException(IPCUtil.java:202)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.onCallFinished(AbstractRpcClient.java:390)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.access$100(AbstractRpcClient.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$3.run(AbstractRpcClient.java:410)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$3.run(AbstractRpcClient.java:406)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.Call.callComplete(Call.java:103)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.Call.setException(Call.java:118)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcDuplexHandler.cleanupCalls(NettyRpcDuplexHandler.java:203)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcDuplexHandler.channelInactive(NettyRpcDuplexHandler.java:211)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:377)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:342)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelInactive(IdleStateHandler.java:277)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1354)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:917)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:822)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
        ... 1 more
    Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
        ... 25 more
```

### Can some one help me out..!

Comment: The error is `ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed`. That could be caused by the query taking too long, and the connection timing out.

Comment: yes.I found that this exception always points to one of the servers,I think I should check the core load of this server

Comment: thx,It still can't be solved. I guess it can be solved through parameter configuration, but I don't have a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## thx everyone,I solved the problem!

The solutions are as follows:
I found the main reason for the abnormality

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=11, exceptions:
Sun Oct 18 10:35:08 CST 2020, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1602988506012, pause=100, maxAttempts=11}, java.io.IOException: Call to CQ-HM-ALIFC-test/10.10.10.10:16020 failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
```

The preliminary judgment is that the RPC has problems,So when I execute the SQL statement, I open the RegionServer log of the server where the error is reported.I found that RegionServer generates the following logs：

```
WARN org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcServer: RPC data length of 353247227 received from 10.10.10.10 is greater than max allowed 268435456. Set "hbase.ipc.max.request.size" on server to override this limit (not recommended)
```

I increased the parameter and solved the problem!